# terminology for what a class does with generic type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given class `MyClass<T>` what is the proper terminology to describe what `MyClass` *does* with the generic type parameter?

Implements? Uses?  These don't sound right.  I've skimmed through MS documentation on generics and they seem to talk around it without using a term.

My question came to mind when writing a comment about code that inspected the type of generic type parameter to see if it was assignable from a particular base type.  I was planning to say something like: "check to see if the generic class *verbs* the specified type".  I can word it differently, but wanted to know if there was a good verb to use.

Comment: Your question is unclear. How would you use such a verb?

Comment: What does a function do with a parameter? Accepts it perhaps? "The generic type/function accepts the generic type parameter".

Comment: With @SLaks here: "can you use it in a sentence"?

Comment: @Slaks -- see my edit. "check to see if the generic class verbs the specified type"

Comment: Just "It uses the type parameter" would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From simple view, you could say that generic function **accepts** a generic type parameter.

You could specialize this to **contains**, but if you want to be fancy, you might say, a generic type [**reifies**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) a type parameter.

From the Wikipedia article:

> "In C#, reification is used to make parametric polymorphism
>   implemented as generics as a first-class feature of the language"

---

The [definition on Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reify)

> re·i·fy/ˈriəˌfaɪ, ˈreɪ-/
>
> **verb** (used with object), re·i·fied, re·i·fy·ing.
>   to convert into or regard as a concrete thing: to reify a concept.

Comment: I will probably stick with /uses/ for my comment, but /reifies/ is what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The `T` parameter is part of the type, so you should just say MyClass of T. It "does" nothing with `T`.

Comment: You can think of T as a parameter of MyClass so MyClass most certainly can "do" something with T.  For instance, you can cast a member to type T.

Answer (score 2):

The way it's used in the MSDN documentation is `MyClass of T`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not do anything with T. T is its parameter.

```
void doNothing(int i)
{
}
```

What does this do with i? Nothing. i is its parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The system binds an open-generic type `MyClass<>` to a particular type (e.g. `Int32`) to yield a closed generic type `MyClass<Int32>`.  The former class is effectively used only as a template for the system to produce the latter; the latter has the type built into it.  Note that the generation of the closed-form generic from the open-form generic is done by the system, and not by the class itself.  A class can include constraints on its generic parameters, but otherwise has no control or involvement in the process.

Comment: so rather than "the generic class /uses/ the type" you suggest a more correct statement to be "the generic class /is bound to/ the type"?

Comment: @Jos.Schlitz: That might be the best terminology, though `MyClass<Int32>` doesn't actually exist until the binding is complete; it's the product of binding `MyClass<>` with type parameter `Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

Type parameterization is what I would call it. Also type specification deferment.

Comment: So MyClass parameterizes the type and defers its specification.

Answer (score 0):

Since `List<int>` is a "List **of** int", probably the 'verb' you're looking for is "the generic class **is of** the specified type"